# SQL count a record in multiple criterias

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the query below with a case statement,

```
  SELECT (CASE  
              WHEN [C1].[Date]>='2012-02-19' 
                   AND [C1].[Date]<='2012-07-29' 
                       THEN 'HY1''12'
              WHEN [C1].[Date]>='2012-08-05' 
                   AND [C1].[Date]<='2013-01-27' 
                       THEN 'HY2''12' 
              WHEN [C1].[Date]>='2013-01-06' 
                   AND [C1].[Date]<='2013-06-30' 
                       THEN 'HY1''13' 
          END) AS [Timeperiod],
         MIN([C1].[Date]),
         MAX([C1].[Date]),
         COUNT([C1].[Date])


    FROM [TABLE_1] AS [C1]
GROUP BY [Timeperiod]
```

Consider a date 2013-01-06, this satisfies multiple criterias i.e. both HY2'12 and HY1'13. This date gets counted only in the HY2'12 using the above case statement. I want a query where this date is counted in both HY2'12 and HY1'13 and the results in a single column, i.e in the above query a column named Timeperiod.

I'm after a table like below,

```
Time Period|Start Date|End Date  |Count

HY2'12     |05-08-2012|27-01-2013|901

HY1'13     |03-02-2013|30-06-2013|900

HY2'13     |07-07-2013|29-12-2013|902

           |19-02-2012|29-07-2012|905
```

Comment: How would you indicate that?  show a list separated by commas?

Comment: please add it to your question so it can be formatted properly - it;s hard to tell what that looks like in a comment.

Comment: You seem to have two questions here: how do you count each criteria, understanding that a record may meet more than one, and how do you pivot it so the criteria is a column and the count is a second.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades, I've edited the query to add the Count column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is separate it into three different queries:

```
SELECT 'HY1''12', MIN([C1].[Date]), MAX([C1].[Date]), COUNT(*)
FROM [TABLE_1] AS [C1]
WHERE [C1].[Date]>='2012-02-19' AND [C1].[Date]<='2012-07-29'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HY2''12', MIN([C1].[Date]), MAX([C1].[Date]), COUNT(*)
FROM [TABLE_1] AS [C1]
WHERE [C1].[Date]>='2012-08-05' AND [C1].[Date]<='2013-01-27'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'HY1''13', MIN([C1].[Date]), MAX([C1].[Date]), COUNT(*)
FROM [TABLE_1] AS [C1]
WHERE [C1].[Date]>='2013-01-06' AND [C1].[Date]<='2013-06-30'
```

I find this cleaner, and I believe it'll give better performance.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this looks much cleaner but I want the results in a single column, as it will be further used in a group by clause.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "a single column". The example you just edited into your question contains four columns, as is the output of the query I suggested.

Comment: Sorry, your query will yield the desired result. But I doubt this will give a better performance as these as three separate queries.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to try both queries and test the performance yourself. Anyway, don't forget to create an index on `Date` - you'll need it, regardless of how you end up solving this.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, I'm on a roll. I want to suggest a different approach. This approach is better if you intend to alter the "reports" that you are generating in the future.

Create a "reports" table:

```
CREATE TABLE reports (name TEXT, start_date TEXT, end_date TEXT);
```

And add your input ranges to it:

```
INSERT INTO reports VALUES ('HY1''12', '2012-02-19', '2012-07-29'), ('HY2''12', '2012-08-05', '2013-01-27'), ('HY1''13', '2013-01-06', '2013-06-30');
```

Then the following query will do the trick:

```
SELECT [reports].[name], [reports].[start_date], [reports].[end_date], COUNT(*)
FROM [TABLE1] AS [C1], [reports]
WHERE [C1].[Date]>=[reports].[start_date] AND [C1].[Date]<=[reports].[end_date]
GROUP BY [reports].[name], [reports].[start_date], [reports].[end_date];
```